# How can i unbind Pusherjs event when component unload when using React Hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, pusher-js

I know that we can bind pusher event like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
    channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
},[]);
```

But i can't find any ways to unbind it when the component unload. Is there some way to unbind it like this

```
useEffect(() => {
     var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
     channel.bind('my-event', function(data) {
       alert(JSON.stringify(data));
     });
     return () => channel.unbind('my-event');
 },[]);
```

Comment: yes this is right way to unbind : return () => channel.unbind('my-event');

Comment: But unbind doesn't exist in vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Pusher JS has an unbind feature, as documented at https://github.com/pusher/pusher-js#binding-to-events

```
// Remove all handlers for the `new-comment` event
channel.unbind('my-event')
```

If this is not working and you are encountering an error please edit your question to include the errors.