# Can i check if pusher is binded in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, pusher

I have pusher in react, and on use effects it binds to event, but when i leave the component and go in the component again it binds again and i get 2 notifications when pusher emmits the event , can i somehow check if pusher is binded to that event?

```
channel.bind(userData.userId, (data: any) => {
      if (data.message.indexOf('failed') > -1) {
        showNotification('warning', 'Your file has failed processing. Please upload it again.');
        setShowProcessing(false)
        setProcessingCategory('')
        setShowError(true)
      }
```

I need one bind only.

Comment: If you are using `useEffect`, you should return a cleanup function that unbinds from the event.

Comment: i need the notification to display even if i leave the component

Comment: You might want to check the channel.unbind method and the useEffect cleanup function for that Markos. Check this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394142/how-can-i-unbind-pusherjs-event-when-component-unload-when-using-react-hook

Comment: Then you should not put the effect in that component at all, but rather in a component that is mounted exactly once.